# Laravel5.2 SQL builder test condition to where query

Tags: sql, laravel-5

I do search function In raw SQL like this

```
//test condition variable
 if ($param_type != "") {
    if($param_type =='SAS'){
        $str .= " AND pos.type IN('SAS1','SAS2') ";
    }
    else if($param_type =='SME'){
        $str .= " AND pos.type IN('SME1','SME2') ";
    }
    else if($param_type =='PT'){
        $str .= " AND pos.type IN('PT','PT0') ";
    }else{
        $str .= " AND pos.type ='$param_type'";
    }
}

//SQL

$query =" SELECT * FROM tbl_user AS u INNER JOIN tbl_position AS pos 
         ON u.user_id = pos.user_id where u.levels IN ('7','8','9') .$str ;" ;
```

How I can write SQL like this in laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **raw query**.

```
$query = DB::select(SELECT * FROM tbl_user AS u INNER JOIN tbl_position AS pos 
     ON u.user_id = pos.user_id where u.levels IN ('7','8','9') .$str ;");
```

Of course then you need to add at the top in your controller `use DB;`

Anyway Raw queries may be dangerous and it's better to use query builder.
Simple example:

```
$query = DB::table('tbl_user')
     ->join('tbl_position','tbl_user.user_id','=','tbl_position.user_id')
     ->where('something','=','something')
     ->get();
```

Query builder: [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries)

Answer (score 0):

Reply to my question for who meet problem like me:

Example like this

```
$query = DB::table('user');

if ($param_type =='PT')
    $query->where('pos.type', '=', 1);
}
 $result = $query->get();
```